# Where is Visual Studio 2015 Extensibility VSIX Project Template for Javascript Language

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vsix

I need to Create vsix project for my javascript based Project,but i am unable to find the 'Extensibility' node in 'Javascript' bar, is there any other workaraound?

[image: Extensibility]

Comment: VSIXes have nothing to do with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio extensions are only created in C# and VB.net project templates.

Comment: Let me know if his helped/answered.